# Killing extra instances of a service and getting notified about them

Tags: kill, background-process, notifications

I have 2 Ruby-on-Rails applications running on my server. Their deployment is automated through Capistrano. The applications uses Sidekiq for processing background jobs.

I use two individual scripts for my 2 applications and those are placed in `/etc/init.d`

```
deployer@experimental:~$ ls -l /etc/init.d/ | grep sidekiq
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 1988 Aug 23  2018 sidekiq_my_app_1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1993 Aug 23  2018 sidekiq_my_app_2
```

The init script is a modified version of sample script shown [here](https://gist.github.com/CD1212/5326706).

I start/stop/restart the script using command like `$ service sidekiq_my_app_1`

In normal circumstances I expect the just 1 Sidekiq process for my each application like following:

```
deployer@experimental:~$ ps aux | grep sidekiq
deployer  1645  0.1  3.5 1150452 144188 ?      Sl   Jul16   4:29 sidekiq 5.0.4 my_app_1 [0 of 10 busy]
deployer  1658  5.4  7.3 1444620 298252 ?      Sl   Jul16 139:11 sidekiq 4.2.2 my_app_2 [0 of 10 busy]
deployer 22759  0.0  0.0  14516   940 pts/2    S+   12:31   0:00 grep sidekiq
deployer@experimental:~$
```

However I have noticed that during automated deployments multiple Sidekiq processes for an application gets started like following

```
deployer@experimental:~$ ps aux | grep sidekiq
deployer  1645  0.1  3.5 1150452 144188 ?      Sl   Jul16   4:29 sidekiq 5.0.4 my_app_1 [0 of 10 busy]
deployer  1658  5.4  7.3 1444620 298252 ?      Sl   Jul16 139:11 sidekiq 4.2.2 my_app_2 [0 of 10 busy]
deployer  1907  2.3  8.1 1703424 331276 ?      Sl   Jul16 150:02 sidekiq 4.2.2 my_app_2 [0 of 10 busy]
deployer 22759  0.0  0.0  14516   940 pts/2    S+   12:31   0:00 grep sidekiq
deployer@experimental:~$
```

which causes unpredictable behaviour of background jobs.

Can anybody please suggest some solutions to automatically address the above problem of shutting down extra processes and retaining just 1, for each application, in the end?

Also it would be a great help if some solutions can be suggested using which I can get notified through Email/SMS about problems like above.

Thanks.